# Where to get a USB type E front panel motherboard header?

Tags: usb, identification, usb-c, bom, sourcing

I'm designing a product that will need to have USB type C ports on its front panel, and due to physical constraints with the design, I would like to use a USB type E connector in conjunction with a front panel cable ([like this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B083FRW542)) to accomplish this.

However, searching various online suppliers, I'm unable to find an actual manufacturer, part, part number, or any kind of datasheet for such a connector.

Here's an image of the connector I'm after:

[image: connector]

(Note that while I'm primarily interested in the female surface-mount connector on the left, if you do happen to know where to get the bare cable-end connector on the cable to the right, that would certainly be helpful as well.)

The [official specification for this connector](https://www.usb.org/sites/default/files/USB3p1_Front_Panel_CabCon_Implment_Doc_Rev1p1.pdf) calls it the "USB 3.1 Front-Panel Internal Connector", but that term isn't turning anything up for me either.

What manufacturers are currently making this connector, and what part numbers should I be searching for?

Comment: Note that direct shopping questions will result in fairly prompt closure of your question as per [site rules](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). You might want to edit that out of your question.

Comment: @Transistor Just to clarify, which section is problematic? I'm not asking for a recommendation; by my reading this falls under the ambit of the [Component Identification Question Guidelines](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6710/component-identification-question-guidelines).

Comment: Your second-last paragraph. "*... where/how can I buy them to use in my project?*"

Comment: @Transistor Oh, ok thanks, I've edited that to just ask about manufacturers/part numbers rather than explicity about where to buy them.

Comment: I suspect these are coming from suppliers like Foxconn, who require zillion piece MOQ.  If USB 3.0 is sufficient, the same function can be accomplished with a much simpler pin header.

Comment: @mbedded For my application I am at least _attempting_ to design it to do 20 Gbps USB 3.2 gen 2x2, but if what you say is true I may just have to put a regular type-c connector and use a type-c extension cable instead of this type-e. In any case if you're able to find a reference on that, that'd make a good answer (although not the one I'd like to hear).

Comment: I can't prove the negative, plus I don't want it to be true.  Type-C would worry me for vibration; if you go that route, I would recommend at least the [screw-lock version.](https://www.usb.org/document-library/usb-type-cr-locking-connector-specification)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to the efforts of user Amyk in [my post on the EEVBlog Forum](https://www.eevblog.com/forum/projects/where-to-get-a-usb-3-1-type-e-front-panel-header/#msg3142380), I now have part numbers from two manufacturers in China.

[C8656-20CFDSAQR from Hsuan Mao Technology Co., Ltd](http://www.hsm.net.tw/product_item.php?fcid=&cid=178&id=2053)
[WU3IR-20A1L1PHW5 from WinWin Precision Industrial Co., Ltd](http://www.winning.com.tw/en/product/product-info.php?id=12930)

Not sure if actually procuring these parts will be practical/cost effective for my project, but at least now I have the information to find that out.